# Unable to successfully dump emails retrieved from gmail to mbox file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written below 2 code snippets. Second one work's as expected but not the first one.I am unable to find out why output list of print(msg_obj.keys()) at line #22 in first snippet doesn't contain 'Subject','From' keys while msg_obj contains header fields like 'Subject','From'. When I dump emails to mbox file using this script and later open that file using some utility(mboxview.exe for windows) ,utility doesn't recognise any email dumped.Please help me out of this. Any suggestions are most welcomed.

```
import imaplib,email,mailbox

M=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com',993)
status,data=M.login('someone@gmail.com', 'password')
M.select()

#create new mbox file if doesn't exist
mbox_file=mailbox.mbox('gmail_mails.mbox')
mbox_file.lock()

#get all mails number   
status,data=M.search(None, 'ALL')

try:
    for mail_no in data[0].split():

        status,msg=M.fetch(mail_no,'(RFC822)')

        msg_obj=email.message_from_string(str(msg[0][1]))

        #print for debugging purpose
        print(msg_obj.keys())
        print(msg_obj["Subject"])

        mbox_msg_obj=mailbox.mboxMessage(msg_obj)

        mbox_file.add(mbox_msg_obj)

        mbox_file.flush()

finally:
    mbox_file.unlock()
    mbox_file.close()

M.close()
M.logout()
```

Also what I found is in case of below code it works:

```
from email.parser import Parser

str="""Received: (qmail 8580 invoked from network); 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22      -0400\r\nReceived: from mail-fx0-f44.google.com (209.85.161.44) by ip-73-187-35-131.ip.secureserver.net with SMTP; 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22 -0400\r\nReceived: by fxm19 with SMTP id 19so170709fxm.3 for <username@domain.com>; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nReceived: by 10.103.84.1 with SMTP id m1mr2774225mul.26.1276652853684; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)\r\nReceived: by 10.123.143.4 with HTTP; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)\r\nDate: Tue, 15 Jun 2010 20:47:33 -0500\r\nMessage-ID: <AANLkTikFsIjJ3KYW1HJWcAqQlGXNiXE2YMzrj39I0tdB@mail.gmail.com>\r\nSubject: TEST 12\r\nFrom: Full Name <username@sender.com>\r\nTo: username@domain.com\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 ONE\nTWO\nTHREE"""

msg=Parser().parsestr(str)

print (msg['Subject'])
print (msg['From'])
print (msg['to'])
```

Here output is

```
TEST 12
Full Name <username@sender.com>
username@domain.com
```

Problem solved using email.parser.BytesParser().parsebytes() instead of email.message_from_string().But not getting why?

Comment: What is the output of the first program? Especially the line `print(msg_obj.keys())`.

Comment: Output is just  ["b'Delivered-To"] for each email .

Comment: An unrelated caution: in your last code snippet you've overwritten `str` which is a Python type.

Answer (score 0):

From your example code, I'm trying the following:

```
import email

estr = """Received: (qmail 8580 invoked from network); 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22      -0400\r\nReceived: from mail-fx0-f44.google.com (209.85.161.44) by ip-73-187-35-131.ip.secureserver.net with SMTP; 15 Jun 2010 21:43:22 -0400\r\nReceived: by fxm19 with SMTP id 19so170709fxm.3 for <username@domain.com>; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nReceived: by 10.103.84.1 with SMTP id m1mr2774225mul.26.1276652853684; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)\r\nReceived: by 10.123.143.4 with HTTP; Tue, 15 Jun 2010 18:47:33 -0700 (PDT)\r\nDate: Tue, 15 Jun 2010 20:47:33 -0500\r\nMessage-ID: <AANLkTikFsIjJ3KYW1HJWcAqQlGXNiXE2YMzrj39I0tdB@mail.gmail.com>\r\nSubject: TEST 12\r\nFrom: Full Name <username@sender.com>\r\nTo: username@domain.com\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 ONE\nTWO\nTHREE"""

msg = email.message_from_string(estr)

print (msg['Subject'])
print (msg['From'])
print (msg['to'])
```

That prints the results fine.

```
TEST 12
Full Name <username@sender.com>
username@domain.com
```

So from your first code snippet, the function input `str(msg[0][1])` must contain some unparsable contents. you'll have to have a closer look at the contents of `str(msg[0][1])` that is failing to parse.